# IIS doesn't recognise view model annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I have a basic MVC view model with annotations, for example:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Your Name Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Your Name")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [MaxLength(120, ErrorMessage = "Must be under 120 characters")]                
    public String  YourName { get; set; }
```

I have a strongly-typed view based upon this view model. When I run the application locally, the following code generates "Your Name" label:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.YourName)
```

When the application is deployed on IIS7 with .NET 4 application pool, the label says "YourName" (without a space).

This is very bizzare and I didn't come across this before. Does anybody have an idea what might be causing this?

Cache is cleared, this has been tested from a range of web clients and result is the same.

**Edit:**

```
@model MVC.Web.Models.ContactUsModel

<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.YourName)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.YourName)       
</div>
```

**Edit 2**
All annotations on that field are being ignored. There are other text type fields and they have the same issue. This is happening only on a live server. Live server is IIS 7 which has been configured over Plesk 10.2. Wondering whether this is a bug since I'm using MVC 3 RTM.

**Edit 3**
Within the same view model I have the Email property:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your Email Is Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Your Email")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$", ErrorMessage = "Your Email Is Invalid")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public String FromEmail { get; set; }
```

This property is used within a view:

```
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FromEmail)    
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FromEmail)        
    </div>
```

But it works perfectly fine :( So the email property works fine in both live and dev environment. Other properties work only in dev environment.

**Edit 4**
Removing MaxLength and MinLength annotations fixed the problem. I would still like to use MaxLength and MinLength annotations as part of my model validation routines though.

```
[MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Minimum 3 Characters")]
[MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Maximum 30 Characters")]
```

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is your build didn't get published. Try rebuilding the solution and republishing the site replacing all documents.

Comment: Hi Jay. I have previously clean-rebuilt solution. Completely remove previous binaries and re-deployed. Issue did not disappear.

Comment: Yes, I can see the label tag, however it is: <label for="YourName">YourName</label>, which is odd.

Comment: shouldn't it be `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.YourName)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FromName)?`

Comment: @Bad Display Name - Hey. EditorFor and LabelFor should refer to the same property within a view model.

Comment: @vikp - can you post the code for `MinLengthAttribute` and `MaxLengthAttribute` since they are not standard attributes - I'm thinking they are generating errors or something that is causing the meta data provider to bunk out

Comment: Sure, please see edit. What do you mean by not standard attributes?

Comment: Just got me thinking, they are part of EntityFramework 4.0

Comment: Have you looked at using `StringLength` rather than `MaxLength` and `MinLength`?

Comment: Just to rule out any version issues between version of mvc installed on your machine, and what the server has: can you bin deploy the mvc 3 files from your machine and into the application folder? http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC3 supports the [StringLength] attribute, while [MinLenght] and [MaxLength] come with Entity Framework.
Could you try this instead of MaxLength?

```
[StringLength(120, ErrorMessage = "Must be under 120 characters")]
```

Comment: That fixes the problem. I still have to find out how to get EF annotations to work. Hopefully it's the case of installing EF extensions or something of that kind on a server. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In your example you have the following property on your Model.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Your Name Required")]
[Display(Name = "Your Name")]
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
[MaxLength(120, ErrorMessage = "Must be under 120 characters")]                
public String  YourName { get; set; }
```

So, the property "YourName" should get a label of "Your Name".

In your view, though, you aren't displaying the YourName property.

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FromName)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FromName)
```

So you need to add similar attributes to your FromName property.

Comment: Hey, that's a typo, it still doesn't fix the problem. I was typing code manually here.

Comment: You might be better off copy-pasting the actual code as maybe there are other bits missing that might make a difference too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very new to razor but I thought DisplayTextFor didn't give you a label.
Wouldn't `@Html.LabelFor()` make more sense?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. Written in notepad.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested this on IIS7 with .NET 4 App Pool, just like in your case and it works absolutely fine for me.
Can you describe how you do your deployment? I did a simple Right Click>Publish in Visual Studio 2010 with default profile.
Also one thing to check is that .NET version installed on the server is up-to-date. It should be v4.0.30319 or over. Perhaps I could email you my solution so you could test it on your server?

Comment: Publishing is done over FileZilla. I.e. I publish to the file system and then copy eveything apart from web.config to the server. Prior to copying, I remove everything from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 2 - My first answer really just points out the mis-type in the question, but based on the comments you've given about your deployment, I think your problem might be related to your deploy, rather than your code.

If you are performing an x-copy deploy, make sure you are copying all the latest DLLs into the bin directory. What I mean is...

- Make sure you build your solution, and the build succeeds
- Copy the newly built DLLs to your web server as well as the other files

The reason for this is that the model will get compiled into these DLLs, so you need to upload them to your live bin folder get your attributes on the server.

If you are uploading your model code files, they aren't actually used on the server... just the bin, views, scripts and content folders normally.

Comment: Hi Sohnee. The builds and changes to model are working fine. I do a fresh publish each time. I think the problem is in EntityFramework annotations. Please see my last edit.

Answer (score 0):

You need the MicrosoftMvcValidation.js scripts included in your project for this to work. Did you, perhaps, remove them or set them not to copy?